# How to use the verb "integrate" in software development?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

I'm a software developer. Sometimes during our daily meetings we use the verb "integrate". I often hear people saying things like "I integrated this functionality IN the project" or "I integrated this functionality ON the project", etc. I'm confused about how use this verb in this context. What is the correct preposition? Should I use a preposition at all? Maybe another verb? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect that as well as people misusing the "wrong" prepositions with ***integrate***, you're also hearing a lot of usages where it's not really the right verb in the first place. To ***integrate** X into Y* normally implies that X "already exists" somewhere *outside of Y* (as well as implying potentially many low-level modifications to allow X to work *within the environment of Y*, because combining them isn't just a simple "plug-in" process). Often, those people could more accurately and simply just say they ***added** [the functionality of] X to Y*.

Comment: I understand. Then `added` would be sometimes a better option.

Comment: The programming term "implemented" is more precise than "added". "Added" can mean you created a stub with a TODO comment. "Implemented" means the work is done. "I implemented *this feature* **in** *that project*."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those uses would not be ideal (and maybe the speakers you mention aren't really using "integrate" properly). In [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integrate), the words "into" and "with" show up. I can think of three constructions:

- Integrate A **into** B
- Integrate A **with** B
- Integrate A **and** B

In all cases, "integrate" is a good choice when two things have been combined, "mixed," or "blended" together. If I introduce a new module into the project, requiring me to adjust multiple services and components, it's fair to represent that as "integrating" the module into the project. If I simply pasted a single line, though, there could be better choices of verb. Another legitimate time that I might describe work as "integration" is when the main focus of my work is to relate two pre-existing things to each other. For instance, I build an API, and build a user interface separately, and then **integrate** the two.

Among other things, sometimes people choose more-impressive or more-formal words to make their work sound more significant. Ultimately, though, this can impede the team effort if it makes it harder to understand what they *really* did, and perhaps backfire in personal ambition, making their accomplishments harder to immediately understand. In many of these cases it might be better to simply say "I **added** [this functionality] to [that feature]."